# Merge 2 csv files rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So i'm trying to predict the winner of a sport game, and i have 2 CSV files. One with the current year statistics and the other with last years statistics.

I would like to merge them but only with the colums from the first file:

So that if the first table has columns 
['Away','Home','Result']

and the second one has ['Away','Home','Match-Rating']

the result would contain ['Away','Home','Result'] and the 'Result' column would contain 0 or other default value if not found in second CSV.

I tried :

```
data = panda.read_csv('PremierLeagueDataSet/19-20.csv')
display(data.head())
data2= panda.read_csv('PremierLeagueDataSet/18-19.csv')
data.append(data2)
```

but gives me a warning and doesn't do the wanted concatenation

> FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version
>   of pandas will change to not sort by default.

Comment: can you show the head of those df and the expected result

Comment: ['Div', 'Date', 'Time', 'HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam'] ==> 1st df     ['Div', 'Date', 'HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam'] ==> 2nd df         And i would like my result to be just like 1st df but for 'Time' to have a generic value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To block *data2.Match-Rating* from appending, invoke *append* passing
*data2* with column names to be included:

```
data.append(data2[['Away', 'Home']], ignore_index=True, sort=False)\
    .replace(np.nan, '')
```

As you can see, I added *ignore_index=True* to avoid repeating indices.
I added also *sort=False* to avoid a warning concerning planned changes
in future versions.

I added also *replace* to change *NaN* values into empty strings.